# How to fix currency format in access from system default to $

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

My system Currency Format is Rs. (Indian) but I want to change my access application currency format to $ but unable to do so. 
For doing that I put below given code in fields property of table and it changed the same but when I tried to use this in continuous form it blocks from entering data by saying "the value you entered isn't valid for this field".

```
 $ #,##0.00
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Format* property of the textbox where you display the values.

Set this to: `$#,##0.00`

Comment: Thanks it's working but the $ sign is sticked with numbers like $444.00 isn't there a way to keep a space in in between ?